# Spring boot katharsis APIs with OAuth2 Configuration not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2, katharsis

We implemented most of the APIs using katharsis library using spring boot project and all APIs were working successfully, but after we added spring OAuth2 configuration to the project the APIs are not working any more and always return 404. 
Please notice that the spring controller works fine but the katharsis resources not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated : I removed Accept:application/json from header and it works.